# Content reloading after x seconds

Tags: jquery

In my index page, there is a div box that shows the last posts on a forum. 
I want it to be reloaded every 10 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     while(1==1)
     {
        $("#lastPosts").delay(10000).load("showLastPosts.php");
     }
});
```

Is this a good idea? Is there a better approach?

Comment: to load where are reading the data from ? should you communicate with server ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#lastPosts").load("showLastPosts.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

Since you're loading remote content, you should also consider the possibility that the AJAX calls could come back in different orders (unlikely, since your interval is 10 seconds). To protect against this, you can use `setTimeout` and a recursive function (as outlined at the bottom of the MDN article):

```
(function getLatestPosts(){  
   setTimeout(function(){   
      $("#latestPosts").load("showLastPosts.php", getLatestPosts);     
  }, 10000);  
})();
```

Comment: Get rid of that `while` loop. You don't want a new timer to be generated every time it loops, do you?

Comment: @Blender: Just a typo--It's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be communicating with server to get the latest details to load to div. So should consider using ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
      $.ajax({
         type : 'GET'
         url: 'showLastPosts.php',
         datatype: 'html',
         success: function(data){
             $("#lastPosts").html(data);
          }
       });
    }, 10000);
});
```